# How to show a description on a Facebook opengraph story styled as a map

Tags: facebook, dictionary, facebook-opengraph, facebook-stream-story

In my app its possible to report accidents. When doing this, the user can post this to Facebook.
I would like to show the accident on a map together with the address.

Because an accident only has a location and an address, I can't give it a title.
But because there is no title, nothing is shown in the box above the map marker.

[image: The story on my timeline]

Also Facebook does not make it possible to to add text above or below the map if you want to show the story as a map instead of an item.

[image]

So where can I put the address? Currently I put it in the description but the description is nowhere visible...

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Wow, of course the one time I ask a question, nobody in the community has an  answer...

Comment: And of course when I finally found question similar to mine on stackoverflow, there is no any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's late, but my answer might help other people.

Your JSON should contain the "og:title" like below

> {     "og:url": "http://samples.ogp.me/887352634705379",
>     "**og:title**": "Sample Itinerary",     "og:type":
>   "namespace:object_type",  "og:image":
>   "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png",
>     "og:description": "",   "fb:app_id": [fb-id] }

Now "Sample Itinerary" will be displayed as the name of the pin.

Comment: Seems like Facebook added this since I asked that question. Although I don't need it anymore since I have switched work places since then, I'll mark it as correct. Thank you for your answer :)